# Maven build successful with JDK6, but failing with JDK7

Tags: maven, java-7

I have a flex application that builds fine with JDK6. Maven debug logs show the following message for a missing POM file:

---

[WARNING] Missing POM for com.adobe.flex.framework:halo:swc:theme:4.5.1.21328: Error resolving project artifact: Failure to find com.adobe.flex.framework:halo:pom:4.5.1.21328 in http://:9999/nexus/content/groups/repositories was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of  has elapsed or updates are forced for project com.adobe.flex.framework:halo:pom:4.5.1.21328

[DEBUG]       com.adobe.flex.framework:halo:swc:theme:4.5.1.21328:compile (selected for compile)

---

With JDK7, however, the missing POM file seems to be a problem. I get the following 'connection timedout' errors:

---

Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.adobe.flex.framework:halo:pom:4.5.1.21328 from/to flexmojos (http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/): Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:949)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:940)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:695)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:689)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.get(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:445)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:460)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputData(LightweightHttpWagon.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:608)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

---

Am I missing some configuration that's required for using Maven with JDK7? I searched, but couldn't find anything. I'd appreciate any help with this. I'm using Maven 3.0.3. and JDK1.7.0_01.

Comment: I have a similar problem: maven doesn't pick up the default profile anymore, since I switched to jdk7. I didn't rootcause it yet.

Answer (score 1):

This error cannot be due to JDK version.  From the outputs it looks like different repositories are in involved in each case...

jdk 6

```
http://:9999/nexus/content/groups/repositories
```

jdk 7

```
http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup
```

You may want to delete the concerned folder (`../com/adobe/flex/framework/halo/4.5.1.21328`) from your local repository and try rebuilding.

Comment: Appreciate your response. I've deleted the folder from the local repository as you suggested. No luck :(. Also, the URL for JDK1.6 above was an editing error. I looked closer and in both cases, Maven is trying to download the pom file from the same URLs. With JDK 1.6, it ignores the issue. With JDK1.7, it fails...Thanks again for your input.